# Removing inverted commas and brackets from python dataframe column items

Tags: python, pandas, string, text, split

df1

```
         Place                             Actor
['new york','washington']         ['chris evans','John']    
['new york','los angeles']        ['kate','lopez']
```

I want to remove brackets and inverted commas from each column items:

Expected output:

df1

```
         Place                 Actor
new york,washington        chris evans,John   
new york,los angeles       kate,lopez
```

My try:

```
cols = [Place,Actor]
df1[cols].apply(lambda x : x [' + ', '.join(df1[cols]) + ']')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) if there are lists:

```
cols = ['Place','Actor']
df1[cols] = df1[cols].apply(lambda x : x.str.join(', '))
```

EDIT: If there are strings use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
cols = ['Place','Actor']
df1[cols] = df1[cols].apply(lambda x : x.str.strip('[]').str.replace("'","", regex=True))
```

Comment: @jezreal the above script is splitting each words of the column items

Comment: @AB14 - what is `print (df['Actor'].head(3).tolist())` ?

Comment: ["[, ', c, h, r, i, s,  , e, v, a, n, s, ', ,,  , ', J, o, h, n, ', ]", "[, ', k, a, t, e, ', ,,  , ', l, o, p, e, z, ', ]"]

Comment: @AB14 - Can you change EDIT?